# jsonschema2pojo gives 1 Properties.java with new POJO for each Json element

Tags: jsonschema2pojo

I am using Java API like this

```
public void convertJsonToJavaClass(URL inputJsonUrl, File outputJavaClassDirectory, String packageName, String javaClassName) throws IOException {
    com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel jcodeModel = new com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel();

    GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {
        @Override
        public boolean isGenerateBuilders() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public SourceType getSourceType() {
            return SourceType.JSON;
        }
    };

    SchemaMapper mapper = new SchemaMapper(new RuleFactory(config, new Jackson2Annotator(config), new SchemaStore()), new SchemaGenerator());
    mapper.generate(jcodeModel, javaClassName, packageName, inputJsonUrl);

    jcodeModel.build(outputJavaClassDirectory);
}
```

The input Json schema file has properties that look like this:

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "Market": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "Dealer": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "Side": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["Buy", "Sell", "Pay", "Receive", "Undisclosed"]
    },
    "Package": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["Y", "N"]
    }
},
"required": ["Market", "Side"]
}
```

The default output is 5 POJO classes, 1 for each Json element with a `Properties.java` to collect all the POJO. Whereas I would like 1 POJO with the Json elements converted to Java primitives. What to do please? Is this Json schema layout and Java API code the best practise for jsonschema2pojo? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using `return SourceType.JSON;` for a `JsonSchema`.

When I changed to `return SourceType.JSONSCHEMA;` it created the 1 POJO class.